# Why I am not getting notification when app is in background? I am using react-native-fcm@16.2.4

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, react-native-router-flux, react-native-fcm

I am facing an issue in receiving the notification when the app is in the background or closed. When I close the app `ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()` method called & notification does not come.

I am using following versions:

- react-native :0.57.5
- react:16.6.3
- node:8.15.0
- npm:6.4.1

Platform: Android

Comment: which platform your facing this issue

Comment: did you read the documentaion for this library.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mn6yzb